# d3.js Common Trait Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1791/

In creating a relationship chart - that shows common traits - I am struggling to create the curved arcs that will match the position of the dots.

What is the best way of plotting these arcs so it dips below the horizon?

```
   var data = [{
     "userName": "Rihanna",
     "userImage": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTzjaQlkAJswpiRZByvgsb3CVrfNNLLwjFHMrkZ_bzdPOWdxDE2Q",
     "userDetails": [{
       "Skills & Expertise": [{
         "id": 2,
         "tag": "Javascript"
       }, {
         "id": 3,
         "tag": "Design"
       }],
       "Location": [{
         "id": 0,
         "tag": "London"
       }, {
         "id": 1,
         "tag": "Germany"
       }],
       "Company": [{
         "id": 0,
         "tag": "The Old County"
       }]
     }]
   }, {
     "userName": "Brad",
     "userImage": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdASQvEzIzE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAls/5vbx7yVLDnc/photo.jpg",
     "userDetails": [{
       "Skills & Expertise": [{
         "id": 0,
         "tag": "JAVA"
       }, {
         "id": 1,
         "tag": "PHP"
       }, {
         "id": 2,
         "tag": "Javascript"
       }],
       "Location": [{
         "id": 0,
         "tag": "London"
       }],
       "Company": [{
         "id": 0,
         "tag": "The Old County"
       }, {
         "id": 1,
         "tag": "Bakerlight"
       }]
     }]
   }]



   var viz = d3.select("#viz")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", 600)
     .attr("height", 600)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(40,100)")


   var patternsSvg = viz
     .append('g')
     .attr('class', 'patterns');


   function colores_google(n) {
     var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
     return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
   }


   function getRadius(d) {
     var count = d.commonTags.split(",").length;
     var ratio = count * 2.3;

     if (count == 1) {
       ratio = 8;
     }

     return ratio;
   }






   //create patterns for user images
   $.each(data, function(index, value) {
     var defs = patternsSvg.append('svg:defs');
     defs.append('svg:pattern')
       .attr('id', index + "-" + value.userName.toLowerCase())
       .attr('width', 1)
       .attr('height', 1)
       .append('svg:image')
       .attr('xlink:href', value.userImage)
       .attr('x', 0)
       .attr('y', 0)
       .attr('width', 75)
       .attr('height', 75);


     console.log(value.userDetails[0]);


   });




   //create common data assement


   var data1 = [{
     "commonLabel": "Groups",
     "commonTags": "test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7"
   }, {
     "commonLabel": "Skills & Expertise",
     "commonTags": "test1, test2, test3, test1, test2, test3, test1, test2, test3, test1, test2"
   }, {
     "commonLabel": "Location",
     "commonTags": "test1"
   }, {
     "commonLabel": "Company",
     "commonTags": "test1"
   }]



   //add curved paths
   var distanceBetween = 70;

   var pathStart = -400;

   var path = viz.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
     .data(data1)

   path
     .enter().append("svg:path")
     .attr("class", function(d) {
       return "link "
     })

   path.attr("d", function(d, i) {
     var sx = 0;
     var tx = 235;

     var sy = 120;
     var ty = 120;


     pathStart += 125;

     var dx = 0;
     var dy = getRadius(d) + (distanceBetween * i) - pathStart;
     var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

     console.log("dy", dy);

     return "M" + sx + "," + sy + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + tx + "," + ty;
   });
   //add curved paths





   //create circles to hold the user images
   var circle = viz.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
     .data(data);

   //enter
   circle
     .enter()
     .append("svg:circle")
     .attr("id", function(d) {
       return d.userName;
     })
     .attr("r", function(d) {
       return "30";
     })
     .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
       return "235" * i;
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
       return "120";
     })
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return "url(#" + i + "-" + d.userName.toLowerCase() + ")";
     })


   var distanceBetween = 65;
   var circle = viz.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
     .data(data1);

   //enter
   circle
     .enter()
     .append("svg:circle")
     .attr("id", function(d) {
       return d.commonLabel;
     })
     .attr("r", function(d) {
       return getRadius(d);
     })
     .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
       return 125;
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
       return distanceBetween * i;
     })
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return colores_google(i);
     });



   var text = viz.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
     .data(data1)

   text
     .enter().append("svg:g");

   text.append("svg:text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("x", "125")
     .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return getRadius(d) + 15 + (distanceBetween * i);
     })
     .text(function(d) {
       return d.commonLabel;
     })
     .attr("id", function(d) {
       return "text" + d.commonLabel;
     });



   var counters = viz.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
     .data(data1)

   counters
     .enter().append("svg:g");

   counters.append("svg:text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("x", "125")
     .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return ((getRadius(d) / 2) + (distanceBetween * i)) - 3;
     })
     .text(function(d) {
       var count = d.commonTags.split(",").length;
       if (count > 1) {
         return count;
       }
     })
     .attr("id", function(d) {
       return "textcount" + d.commonLabel;
     });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/554/ - latest user chart development

Comment: How do I go about drawing the paths - http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/drawing-svg-path-using-d3js.html - Do I just create an svg path and try and push the two cx, cy points to form the line? - how would I make it bend though

Comment: Would it be best to try and create arcs like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/CrDUy/

Comment: latest version - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/556/

Comment: I've tried batching the svg objects together - but something has gone wrong, some kind of displacement bug - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/562/

Comment: This shows curved paths using nodes - http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/BcW8z/

Comment: How would I attach curved paths to this?

Comment: includes label enhancements - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/660/

Comment: enhancements -http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/661/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1781/  -- cleaned up to just the path

Comment: So you want all the arcs cross through the dots like the first arc in the image?

Comment: That is correct -- essentially have the arcs curve around and connect to EACH dot -- so its like the first "group" dot at the top

Comment: Would also need to solve this issue with merging the data - so only common traits remain - then you can cleanly plot related aspects  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306832/javascript-merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-with-common-matching-elements

Comment: Also @blackmiaool - similar concept with control over curved paths -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432101/d3-js-network-curved-path-control

Comment: So the effect should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT1md.png), right?

Comment: yeah - that's right

Comment: What's the merging rule do you want? Same id and/or same tag? For example, the number of `Skills & Expertise` should be 1 or 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/blackmiaool/p58a0w3h/1/

First of all, you should remove all the **magic numbers** to keep the code clean and portable.

This one, for example:

```
pathStart += 125;
```

How to draw arcs correctly is a math problem. The code is as blow:

```
path.attr("d", function (d, i) {
    const sx = 0;    
    const sy = height/2;

    const a=width/2;
    const b = ((data1.length-1)/2-i)*distanceBetween;
    const c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    const angle=Math.atan(a/b);
    let r;
    if(b===0){
        r=0;
    }else{
        r=1/2*c/Math.cos(angle);//also equals c/b*(c/2)
//  r=c/b*(c/2);
    }

    return `M${sx},${sy} A${r},${r} 0 0,${b>0?1:0} ${width},${height/2}`;
});
```

And the diagram:

[image]

Comment: nicely explained.

Comment: -- this may solve the merging data bit - if you can explain that too - even more awesome. --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306832/javascript-merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-with-common-matching-elements/43308557#43308557

Comment: @The Old County  time to sleep, see u tomorrow

Comment: I've added the merging feature --- but the paths break if there are less than 4 groups -- so it may not work with dynamic data -- http://jsfiddle.net/zzwo4hnw/3/

Comment: --- this version tries to comment on the maths -- http://jsfiddle.net/zzwo4hnw/4/ -- there is a constant here 1.5 to calculate b -- is that causing a bug

Comment: @TheOldCounty  So I added the merging code to my jsfiddle, and it works now. Is there anything else need to be done? Seems the merging code is too plain to be explained.

Comment: -- give it a check to see if the data changes the code still holds up -- when I removed it to just 3 traits it failed

Comment: -- check this problem too - @blackmiaool  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432101/d3-js-network-curved-path-control

Comment: -- if there is only 1 group the code breaks -- looks like distancebetween becomes infinity -

Comment: -- if there are a number of common traits like they both worked in 2+ companies -- then the circle needs to be bigger  - http://jsfiddle.net/zzwo4hnw/10/

Comment: @TheOldCounty  Is there anything else need to be done? The bugs above seems all be fixed in your last fiddle.

Comment: Yeah I think its ok - is your latest fiddle stable/complete -- I think you tested the first user with emptying out their data

Comment: @TheOldCounty  Yeah.. I forked your new fiddle to my answer.

Comment: Sure man - will need a few hours before the bounty could be rewarded -- be great to review the other chart examples  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432101/d3-js-network-curved-path-control

Comment: @TheOldCounty  Thanks, but it's work time now. Maybe next time.

Comment: Sure - no rush - keep an eye on it. I am not sure how to apply the maths to some of these arcs - but what you say does make sense.

Comment: Cheers @blackmiaool -- try and look at these other chart problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292703/d3-js-timeline-relationship-chart  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432101/d3-js-network-curved-path-control and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087276/d3-line-circle-chart/43285425#43285425

Comment: @blackmiaool merged this bar/water/dotted path line chart - but again got issues plotting the paths and clearing up the code base -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927