# Javascript merging two multidimensional arrays with common matching elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two multi-dimensional arrays and would like to merge this into a single data source that contains only the common matching tags.

//jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10173/

//array 1

```
    var array1 = [{
            "Skills & Expertise": [{
              "id": 2,
              "tag": "Javascript"
            }, {
              "id": 3,
              "tag": "Design"
            }],
            "Location": [{
              "id": 0,
              "tag": "London"
            }, {
              "id": 1,
              "tag": "Germany"
            }],
            "Company": [{
              "id": 0,
              "tag": "Cheesestrings"
            }]
}];
```

//array 2

```
var array2 = [{
            "Skills & Expertise": [{
              "id": 0,
              "tag": "JAVA"
            }, {
              "id": 1,
              "tag": "PHP"
            }, {
              "id": 2,
              "tag": "Javascript"
            }],
            "Location": [{
              "id": 0,
              "tag": "London"
            }],
            "Company": [{
              "id": 0,
              "tag": "Cheesestrings"
            }, {
              "id": 1,
              "tag": "Bakerlight"
            }]
          }]
```

so the outcome should look like this

//desired outcome

```
  var array3 = [{
                "Skills & Expertise": [{
                  "id": 2,
                  "tag": "Javascript"
                }],
                "Location": [{
                  "id": 0,
                  "tag": "London"
                }],
                "Company": [{
                  "id": 0,
                  "tag": "Cheesestrings"
                }]
    }];
```

Would I start out by merging both arrays using a contact -- and then removing elements that don't exist in both?

```
var array3 = array1.concat(array2); // Merges both arrays
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table which reflects the array items and use a nested approach for getting the hash and the result set.

```js
var array1 = [{ "Skills & Expertise": [{ id: 2, tag: "Javascript" }, { id: 3, tag: "Design" }], Location: [{ id: 0, tag: "London" }, { id: 1, tag: "Germany" }], Company: [{ id: 0, tag: "Cheesestrings" }] }],
    array2 = [{ "Skills & Expertise": [{ id: 0, tag: "JAVA" }, { id: 1, tag: "PHP" }, { id: 2, tag: "Javascript" }], Location: [{ id: 0, tag: "London" }], Company: [{ id: 0, tag: "Cheesestrings" }, { id: 1, tag: "Bakerlight" }] }],
    hash = [],
    result;

array1.forEach(function (o, i) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k].forEach(function (a) {
            hash[i] = hash[i] || {};
            hash[i][[k, a.tag].join('|')] = true;
        });
    });
});

result = array2.map(function (o, i) {
    var temp = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k].forEach(function (a) {
            if ((hash[i] || {})[[k, a.tag].join('|')]) {
                temp[k] = temp[k] || [];
                temp[k].push(a);
            }
        });
    });
    return temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello @Nina Scholz have another problem you could maybe help resolve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927