# d3 curved legend with rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I'm trying to create a curved legend using d3. I've created a curved path - but I am unsure how to plot the legend against the path with the labels/rectangles rotated accordingly.

//latest jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1768/

```
labels.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .append('textPath')
  .attr('xlink:href', '#label-path')
  .attr('startOffset', function(d, i) {
    return i * 100 / numBars + 50 / numBars + '%';
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

Comment: I've tried adapting something like this - but no luck - http://jsfiddle.net/LMF9h/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/*Latest Jsfiddle*/

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1779/

I could find out another way to implement this functionality. Hope this helps.

```js
var pi = Math.PI;
var outerRadius = 300;
var w = 1200,
  h = 900;
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1200).attr("height", 900).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(200," + (h / 2) + ")");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(outerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI);

var path = vis
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", "red");

var data = [
  "a blink of an eye",
  "it is all the same",
  "something memorable",
  "when you figure out your birthday is in a month",
  "an event",
  "something special or unique that stands out in your mind",
  "something that happens",
  "a space in time",
  "a minute, a second or a tenth of a second",
  "inevitable",
  "a piece of time",
  "everything all at one time",
  "umm. uh",
  "a rush of warm tingle in my chest followed my a slight dizziness",
  "an indefinitely short period of time: instant",
  "something or anything that can be defined that capture",
  "a minute portion or point of time",
  "anything from the wind blowing a leaf, to your child",
  "something that takes less than a second to witness, but you can remember for a lifetime",
  "a very brief period of time comes to an almost complete stop",
  "a small piece of a bigger collection",
  "a small period of time",
  "the period of time when I'm eating my bagel",
  "an infinite period of time",
  "a blip of space where 1,000,00-million microcosms are coliding into each other",
  "special",
  "hazy and uncoordinated",
  "a given instance",
  "an indefintely short time",
  "enough time to think about something or do something",
  "enlightening",
  "something that sticks with you through your busy life",
  "something I don't have very much of",
  "a memory in time",
  "the first time she lays her hand on yours",
  "here and now: at this time",
  "something or anything that can be defined, that captures your attention in a instance",
  "a turning force produced by an object acting at a distance",
  "the lowest increment of a length of time",
  "a medieval unit of time equal to 1.5 minutes of 1/40 of an hour",
  "when time slows and you to come to realization about something important",
  "in modern english it usually refers to a short period of time",
  "when you look away and your child destroys something expensive",
  "a cluster of data in the program of life",
  "something between two people that is so special that is pondered after the momentum",
  "mmaraow...prrrrot",
  "the present time or any other particular time",
  "a piece of time independent from normal time",
  "90 seconds",
  "a span of time describing a specific instance or event",
  "a period of time where something significant begins",
  "right now"
];

function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#e9168a", "#f8dd2f", "#448875", "#c3bd75", "#2b2d39", "#311854", "#553814", "#f7b363", "#89191d", "#c12f34", "#2b2a2c", "#c5b8a6", "#57585b"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

var noOfRects = data.length;
var rectSize = totalLength / (noOfRects * 3);
var len = 0;
var margin = 5;
var centroid = arc.centroid();;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var pt1 = path.node().getPointAtLength(len);

  len += rectSize;

  var pt2 = path.node().getPointAtLength(len);
  vis.append('path')
    .attr('stroke', function() {
      return colores_google(i);
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 10)
    .attr("d", "M" + pt1.x + "," + pt1.y + "L" + pt2.x + "," + pt2.y + "Z");

  len += margin;


  var v1 = {
      x: pt2.x,
      y: pt2.y
    },
    v2 = {
      x: centroid[0],
      y: centroid[1]
    };

  var angleRad = Math.acos(v1.x / Math.sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y))

  angleDeg = angleRad * 180 / Math.PI;
  angleDeg = i <= data.length / 2 ? angleDeg * -1 : angleDeg;
  vis.append('text')
    .attr("dx", "1.1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pt2.x + "," + pt2.y + ")  rotate(" + angleDeg + ")")
    .text(data[i]);

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #412011;
}

text {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've improved the code base -- could eliminate the invisible path -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1779/  @Gilsha

Comment: Cheers @Gilsha - try these other problems -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175656/d3-js-hybrid-curved-label-bar-pie-chart/43242202#43242202 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087276/d3-line-circle-chart

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect snippet. But, hope this helps. Improve by yourselves.

```js
var $this = $("#progress");


var data = [
  "a blink of an eye",
  "it is all the same",
  "something memorable",
  "when you figure out your birthday is in a month",
  "an event",
  "something special or unique that stands out in your mind",
  "something that happens",
  "a space in time",
  "a minute, a second or a tenth of a second",
  "inevitable",
  "a piece of time",
  "everything all at one time",
  "umm. uh",
  "a rush of warm tingle in my chest followed my a slight dizziness",
  "an indefinitely short period of time: instant",
  "something or anything that can be defined that capture",
  "a minute portion or point of time"
];


var w = 600;
var h = 600;

var radius = Math.min(w, h) / 2;

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")

var labelsrects = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labelsrects");

var labels = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#e9168a", "#f8dd2f", "#448875", "#c3bd75", "#2b2d39", "#311854", "#553814", "#f7b363", "#89191d", "#c12f34", "#2b2a2c", "#c5b8a6", "#57585b"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}

var numBars = data.length;


var arcradius = 150;
var rectWidth = 15;
// Approx number of rects we can fit around the circumference
var n = (Math.PI * 2 * arcradius) / (2 * rectWidth);

labelsrects.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 15)
  .attr('height', 15)
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return "rotate(" + (ang * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (90 + rectWidth + 5) + ")";
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.sin(ang);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.cos(ang);
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colores_google(i);
  });

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

labels.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return "rotate(" + (ang * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (90 + rectWidth + 5) + ")";
  })
   .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.sin(ang);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.cos(ang);
  })
  .attr("dx", rectWidth*2+"px")
  .attr("dy", (rectWidth-5)+"px")
  .style('text-anchor', 'start')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #412011;
}

path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #eeeeee;
}

text {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried to increase the radius -- but the labels and the rectangles don't adjust accordingly

Comment: If you want to increase the radius, either you should increase the size of the rectangle OR number of rectangles accordingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1773/  -- so I've added more data -- and increased the size of the svg -- and arcradius to 300 -- but the rects/labels no longer sync

Comment: -- I've tried to link these two parts together - but need to space the text/rects out more --- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1776/

Comment: Hello @Gilsha anymore enhancements to this. I've tried to connect the rects/labels more in this -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1776/

Comment: Check my new answer.

Comment: Hello @Gilsha - have another problem you could maybe help resolve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've combined the rectangles and labels more closely - but this still lacks the control to space out the labels/rects - and control the radius of the arc.

//latest jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1776/

```
var arcradius =350;
var rectWidth = 10;
// Approx number of circles we can fit around the circumference
var n = (Math.PI * 2 * arcradius) / (2 * rectWidth);

labelsrects.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return "rotate(" + (ang * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (90 + rectWidth + 5) + ")";
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.sin(ang);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.cos(ang);
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colores_google(i);
  });

//var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

labels.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return "rotate(" + (ang * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (90 + rectWidth + 5) + ")";
  })
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.sin(ang);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    var ang = (Math.PI * 2 * i) / n;
    return arcradius * Math.cos(ang);
  })
  .attr("dx", "1.1em")
  .style('text-anchor', 'start')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```